# data not passing inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a function that passes multiple data from JSON using for-each and then called that inside render,  but am not getting any response inside that scop, any idea why is it so?

my function looks as follows:

```
 color=(data)=>{
       this.state.data.colors.forEach(function(color){
        console.log(color)
        return(
          <View>
<TouchableOpacity>
            <Button value= {color.color} />
</TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )
       })
      }
```

And I have called it inside my render function as follows:

```
<View>
{this.color()}
<View>
```

My logs shows this.state.data.colors as undefined inside this scope,can anyone please suggest what am doing wrong?

Any help would be useful, do tell me if you require anything else.

Comment: what is console.log(color) showing?

Comment: Does `this.state.data.colors` has value in render() before calling the function?

Comment: Undefined @yesIamFaded

Comment: and if you replace that log with console.log(this.state.data.colors) or console.log(this.state.data) ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the best help, please update your question with the `colors` array. Although you can try these.

1)
Your function `this.color()` is expecting an argument `data`. But when it was called in the `Views` component, no argument was passed.

Remove `data` from the argument passed into `this.color()`. I see you are not using it in your function.

2)
Confirm that your State is structured like so `data.colors`. Meaning the `colors` is an array is inside the `data` node. I suspect `colors` itself is the parent node not `data`. Hence, the right way to obtain your state values will be `this.state.colors`, not `this.state.data.colors`

3)
Confirm that `color` is a  key in the `colors` array.

i.e

```
 colors:[{color: #00FFDE}, {color: #00FFDE}]
```

Per your function, you are right! `color.color` is correct

But if it is like so

```
colors:[{name: #00FFDE}, {name: #00FFDE}]
```

Per your function, the right thing will be `color.name`

Hope this helps!.